# Build new array from existing array with same datatypes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having this array

```
per= { "advanced_reference_columns": [
        0
    ]
}
```

Then i used "for in" to create another array with same values

```
for (var o in per) {
snapshot_settings[o] = per[o];
}
```

but When I print snapshot_settings it returns its values as string with double quotes

```
"advanced_reference_columns": [
        "0"
    ]
```

Comment: *"I'm having this array"* That's not an array. That's an *object* with a property, `advanced_reference_columns`. The value of that *property* is a reference to an array.

Comment: yeah, by mistake i wrote array, its an object. But how to solve this issue. I defined var snapshot_settings = {}; as an object

Comment: *"but When I print snapshot_settings it returns its values as string with double quotes"* That code should not have that effect, and [doesn't in my test](http://jsbin.com/adAMuh/1) (open the console to see the results). Your code *does* have the problem that `per.advanced_reference_columns` and `snapshot_settings.advanced_reference_columns` both end up referring to the **same** array.

Comment: I have checked the console, both are different, snapshot_settings with double quotes as string and per with single quotes as integer value.

Comment: that because its iterating every value as string("0") where as in your original it was numeric 0. otherwise their is not difference

Comment: @VipulSharma: No, neither of them has any quotes, because the values are not strings. See: http://i.stack.imgur.com/EmY41.png

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I want to share image, but no option. I can show you the difference. Issue is there.

Comment: @VipulSharma: There are **dozens** of image sharing sites on the web, and you can post links. Bottom line, the code you've quoted does not have the effect you've quoted. Full stop. If you're seeing something different, the options are: 1. The code isn't what you've shown, 2. The tool you're using to look at it is misleading, or 3. You're misinterpreting what you're seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
   var newObject = jQuery.extend({}, per);
```

Comment: I have tried this: snapshot_settings = $.extend({}, per); but issue is still there